# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'xty1kq00oktl2omikmznuqle' to data type int

Tags: asp.net

when i'm tying to develop the unlimited scrolling for my data list i'm facing some errors like "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'xty1kq00oktl2omikmznuqle' to data type int."what is this error.and what is wrong in my code.

```
if (Session["id"] != null)
{
mydb db = new mydb();
//Fetch records initially.
 DataSet dsProducts = db.GetProducts();
/ /Bind data to gridview
dl.DataSource = dsProducts;
 dl.DataBind();
    }

 }


  }

    public class mydb
  {
  private SqlConnection con;
   public mydb()
  {
   con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
     }

public DataSet GetProducts()

{

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select top 5 decription,url from tb_userdata inner join tb_userlogin on tb_userdata.uidfromtb1=tb_userlogin.id where tb_userlogin.id=@id", con);
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
      DataSet ds = new DataSet();
   da.Fill(ds);
      return ds;
      error:Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'xty1kq00oktl2omikmznuqle' to data type int.i have little bit confusion at this error
       }

       public DataSet FetchNextProducts(int id, int recordsCount)
         {
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
      string query = string.Format("select top {0} * from tb_userdata inner join tb_userlogin on tb_userdata.uidfromtb1=tb_userlogin.id where tb_userlogin.id=@id ASC", id);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
   SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
     }

     how can i overcome this

      Thanks and Regards
```

Comment: The "id" you add as a parameter is apparently of string type. The snippet however misses its definition.

Comment: sorry for that, protected void btnGetMoreRecords_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            mydb db = new mydb();
            //Fetch 5 records initially.
          
             DataSet dsProducts = db.FetchNextProducts(Convert.ToInt32(hiddenLastProductID.Value), 5);
            
            dl.DataSource = dsProducts;
            dl.DataBind();.......this is the one i've missed.....FetchNextProducts(Convert.ToInt32(hiddenLastProductID.Value), 5); i think this where i'm getting the problem.can you please tell me how can i overcome this..Thnaks